# Passport RFID chip failure

Tags: passports

An American passport's RFID chip is broken (it never did work).  I was forced from the machine automated customs lane to your friendly neighorhood customs agent.  Other than this inconvenience, is there any reason to seek a replacement RFID chip (passport)?

Comment: your passport is invalid without a chip, I believe

Comment: @MatthewBarclay The passport remains valid but with a broken chip you can no longer use expedited immigration facilities which require it such as the APC kiosks in the US or the passport gates in UK and Australia.